# How can I mount an Apple Time Capsule in FreeBSD (FreeNAS) as a smbfs share?

Tags: mount, freebsd, samba, freenas

I am trying to mount a 3rd generation Apple AirPort Time Capsule share on a FreeNas box.

I can connect to the share using *smbclient* and the remoteUser password.

```
% smbclient -U remoteUser -L //AppleTimeCapsule
Enter remoteUser's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Apple Base Station] Server=[CIFS 4.32]
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    remoteUser        Disk
    IPC$            IPC
    otherShare            Disk
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Apple Base Station] Server=[CIFS 4.32]
    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
```

I mount the drive (password is in ~/.nsmbrc)...

```
% cat ~/.nsmbrc
[APPLETIMECAPSULE:REMOTEUSER]
password=myPassword
% mkdir /mnt/atc
% mount_smbfs -I AppleTimeCapsule //remoteUser@AppleTimeCapsule/remoteUser /mnt/atc
% mount | grep 'AppleTimeCapsule'
//REMOTEUSER@APPLETIMECAPSULE/REMOTEUSER on /mnt/atc (smbfs)
% ls /mnt/atc
./  ../
% echo 1 > /mnt/atc/newFile
/mnt/atc/newFile: No such file or directory.
```

It seems to be mounted but there are no files, which I know isn't true. And I can't create a file.

I read (http://blog.martinshouse.com/2014/09/mounting-apple-time-capsule-share-from.html) that the Time Capsules require NTLM authentication and I have managed to read and write under Raspbian like this:

```
# mount -t cifs //AppleTimeMachine/remoteUser -o uid=1001,gid=1004,sec=ntlm,username=remoteUser,password=myPassword /mnt/atc
```

I suspect the key to this is to the *sec=ntlm* but I can't see in the FreeBSD manual how I should apply this. Can I specify ntlm with *mount_smbfs*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question after some more searching:

I understand that this can't be done like this because *mount_smbfs* is FreeBSD-specific and it hasn't kept pace with samba features available in Linux (whereas *smbclient* has).

This isn't quite the end though. You can run a virtual Linux machine in a jail on FreeNas and then connect to the Time Capsule from there.